# toggle class on parent div on click (or ng-click)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some collapseable panels and i want to add a resize button. For this i've made this javascript code:

```
function myFunction () {
    $(".elementoGrafico").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("col-md-12");
        $(this).toggleClass("col-md-6");
    });
};
```

the html code is:

```
<div class="col-md-12 ui-state-default elementoGrafico">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading ">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" class="component-button max-min-button more-less glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></a>
                   <a href="#" class="component-button resize-button glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small" onclick="myFunction.call(this)"></a>
                   Gráfico 1
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in elemento"> <canvas class="chart" id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work properly. Sometimes i have to click more than one time and some times the chart inside don't resizes like the div. (i want a code that works for all elements, not just one, so i want to do it using class, not id.)

I could use angularjs too.

Thank you.

Comment: either you should not use jquery with `angularjs` or your qstn tag should be `jquery`. :)

Comment: `I could use angularjs too.` You are willing to introduce a complete new dependency to your project just to add resizing to your panels? I wouldn't be so hasty, unless you already use Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(".elementoGrafico").each(function() {
  let panel = this;
  $(this).find(".resize-button").click(function() {
    $(panel).toggleClass("col-md-12");
    $(panel).toggleClass("col-md-6");
  });
});
```

What this does is find the resize button for each panel and assign it a click handler which changes the panel itself.

Comment: thank you, it worked, but i have one more question. The canvas inside the panels, that is populated with a chart, sometimes don't resize. why?